# What do square brackets mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and have read a tutorial where I did not understand something in the code:

What does it mean when `$names = [];` is in a PHP script?

Comment: @TiesenT actually this article presents a different use for `[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its the same as `array()`. This syntax is valid since PHP 5.4.

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Comment: Well, but I don't recommend to use this syntax, for the sake of readability.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Pretty readable to me. JavaScript uses the same syntax.